# What is the default value of variable in for...of loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

What will be the default type of the variable in for..of loop.

```js
for (value of [1,2,3]) // what is the default type of value
  console.log(value)
```

I want to know whether `value` type will be var/let/const.

As far I know any undeclared variable will be of type `var`. Is it applies to for loop variables?

Comment: yes, completely agree :) @jfriend00 I was just curious about this.

Comment: @jfriend00 I mean, `let value = null; for (value of values) ; console.log('last:', value)` would work fine :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, but that's not what the OP is asking about.  They are asking about using an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no default, though I guess you could call [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)¹ in loose mode a kind of default. :-) Don't rely on the horror of implicit globals, it's effectively a bug in the language that's fixed by strict mode. :-)

If you write the code the way you have, you have to declare the variable prior to the loop. If you don't, in loose mode, a global `var` is implicitly created; in strict mode (which I recommend using at all times), it's an error. If you declare the variable prior to the loop, either `let` or `var` (but not `const`) will work.

If you declare the variable *in* the loop, you can use either `let` or `const`, depending on whether you want to update the variable in the loop (and also on your preferred style):

```js
const values = ["one", "two", "three"];

for (const value of values) {
    console.log(value);
}

for (let value of values) {
    console.log(value);
}

for (let value of values) {
    // (Note the following only changes the value of the variable, not the entry in the array)
    value = value.toUpperCase(); // You couldn't do thsi with `const`
    console.log(value);
}
```

---

¹ *(that's a post on my anemic, neglected blog)*